# Date columns with NAs in R - unexpected behaviour with mutate

Tags: r, na, dplyr

I'm trying to follow this process with a dataset.
Here is a test dataframe:

```
id <- c("Johnboy","Johnboy","Johnboy")
orderno <- c(2,2,1)
validorder <- c(0,1,1)
ordertype <- c(95,94,95)
orderdate <- as.Date(c("2019-06-17","2019-03-26","2018-08-23"))

df <- data.frame(id, orderno, validorder, ordertype, orderdate)
```

Then I do the following:

```
## compute order date for order types
df <- df %>%
  mutate(orderdate_dried = if_else(validorder == 1 &
                                  ordertype == 95,
                                  orderdate, as.Date(NA)),
         orderdate_fresh = if_else(validorder == 1 &
                                  ordertype == 94,
                                  orderdate, as.Date(NA)))

## take minimum order date by type by order number
df <- df %>%
  group_by(id, orderno) %>%
  mutate(orderdate_dried = min(orderdate_dried, na.rm = TRUE),
         orderdate_fresh = min(orderdate_fresh, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()

## aggregate order date for each type over individual
df <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(max_orderdate_dried = max(orderdate_dried, na.rm=TRUE),
         max_orderdate_fresh = max(orderdate_fresh, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

But all the maximum dates at the end of this process are NA! I don't understand how? Further, if I test the original `orderdate_dried` for NAs:

```
is.na(df$orderdate_dried)
```

I get NAs for each row! How is this happening?!

Comment: View `df` after each mutaate statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very interesting question and the answer is hidden in the question itself. For clarity instead of updating the same `df` everytime I will use `df1`, `df2` etc.

Let's first start with data.

```
id <- c("Johnboy","Johnboy","Johnboy")
orderno <- c(2,2,1)
validorder <- c(0,1,1)
ordertype <- c(95,94,95)
orderdate <- as.Date(c("2019-06-17","2019-03-26","2018-08-23"))

df <- data.frame(id, orderno, validorder, ordertype, orderdate)

library(dplyr)
```

**Step 1 -**

```
df1 <- df %>%
        mutate(orderdate_dried = if_else(validorder == 1 &
                                         ordertype == 95,
                                        orderdate, as.Date(NA)),
               orderdate_fresh = if_else(validorder == 1 &
                                         ordertype == 94,
                                         orderdate, as.Date(NA)))

df1
#       id orderno validorder ordertype  orderdate orderdate_dried orderdate_fresh
#1 Johnboy       2          0        95 2019-06-17            <NA>            <NA>
#2 Johnboy       2          1        94 2019-03-26            <NA>      2019-03-26
#3 Johnboy       1          1        95 2018-08-23      2018-08-23            <NA>
```

Everything as expected here.

**Step 2 -**

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
        group_by(id, orderno) %>%
        mutate(orderdate_dried = min(orderdate_dried, na.rm = TRUE),
                orderdate_fresh = min(orderdate_fresh, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
        ungroup()

df2
# A tibble: 3 x 7
#  id      orderno validorder ordertype orderdate  orderdate_dried orderdate_fresh
#  <fct>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl> <date>     <date>          <date>         
#1 Johnboy       2          0        95 2019-06-17 NA              2019-03-26     
#2 Johnboy       2          1        94 2019-03-26 NA              2019-03-26     
#3 Johnboy       1          1        95 2018-08-23 2018-08-23      NA
```

Everything seems as expected here as well, we get `NA` when there is no other date in the group.

**Step 3 -**

```
df3 <- df2 %>%
        group_by(id) %>%
        mutate(max_orderdate_dried = max(orderdate_dried, na.rm=TRUE),
               max_orderdate_fresh = max(orderdate_fresh, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
         ungroup()

df3
# A tibble: 3 x 9
#  id      orderno validorder ordertype orderdate  orderdate_dried orderdate_fresh max_orderdate_dried max_orderdate_fresh
 #  <fct>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl> <date>     <date>          <date>          <date>              <date>             
#1 Johnboy       2          0        95 2019-06-17 NA              2019-03-26      NA                  NA                 
#2 Johnboy       2          1        94 2019-03-26 NA              2019-03-26      NA                  NA                 
#3 Johnboy       1          1        95 2018-08-23 2018-08-23      NA              NA                  NA
```

Everything seems to be wrong here. These are basically the same steps that you have performed and this is the same output that you are getting, so we haven't done anything different till here.

One thing which we have missed though is in step 2 we received a warning message.

> Warning messages:
>   1: In min.default(c(NA_real_, NA_real_), na.rm = TRUE) :
>     no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
>   2: In min.default(NA_real_, na.rm = TRUE) :
>     no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

Because we had no non-NA value in a group it returned `Inf` even though the output of `df2` shows NA (why it shows `NA` when the value is `Inf`  added the explanation for it at the end of the answer). So even if you test `is.na` with it, it fails.

```
is.na(df2$orderdate_dried)
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Hence, `max` with `na.rm` fails too.

```
 max(df2$orderdate_dried, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] NA
```

Hence, you get all `NA`s in step 3.

---

**Solution**

The solution is to check with `is.finite`

```
df3 <- df2 %>%
        group_by(id) %>%
         mutate(max_orderdate_dried = max(orderdate_dried[is.finite(orderdate_dried)], na.rm=TRUE),
                 max_orderdate_fresh = max(orderdate_fresh[is.finite(orderdate_fresh)], na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
         ungroup()


df3
# A tibble: 3 x 9
#  id      orderno validorder ordertype orderdate  orderdate_dried orderdate_fresh max_orderdate_dried max_orderdate_fresh
#  <fct>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl> <date>     <date>          <date>          <date>              <date>             
#1 Johnboy       2          0        95 2019-06-17 NA              2019-03-26      2018-08-23          2019-03-26         
#2 Johnboy       2          1        94 2019-03-26 NA              2019-03-26      2018-08-23          2019-03-26         
#3 Johnboy       1          1        95 2018-08-23 2018-08-23      NA              2018-08-23          2019-03-26
```

---

**Why does it show value as `NA` when the value is `Inf` ?**

In step 2, what we are basically doing is

```
min(NA, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] Inf
```

> Warning message:
>   In min(NA, na.rm = TRUE) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

This returns `Inf` with a warning which we get.

However, since we know that a column can hold a value of only one `class`.

```
class(Inf) #is
#[1] "numeric"
```

but we have data of class "Date" in `df1`'s `orderdate_dried` column

```
 class(df1$orderdate_dried)
#[1] "Date"
```

so `Inf` is then coerced into class "Date" which returns.

```
as.Date(min(NA, na.rm = TRUE))
#[1] NA
```

Again this is returns `NA` but it is not real `NA` and `is.na` fails on this

```
is.na(as.Date(min(NA, na.rm = TRUE)))
#[1] FALSE
```

hence, step 3 doesn't work as expected.

I hope this answer is clear and not too confusing.

Comment: Great answer @Ronak Shah and very succinct and clear. I've come across issues with NAs in a date column before but tended to impute a extreme high or low date to get around this issue, but this is really useful. Thanks!