# pmin( , na.rm=T) returns NA when comparing dates generated using ave()

Tags: r, date, na, infinity

While writing this question I found a sticking plaster fix, but decided to post anyway because it took me a day to work out. The ultimate problem I eventually found  is that min(..., na.rm=T) on dates that are all NA produces a result that looks like NA, but is actually -Inf. And in subsequent processing they are not treated as NA's.

```
> mymindate <- min(structure(c(NA), class = "Date"), na.rm=T)
Warning message:
In min.default(NA, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
> mymindate  # appears to be NA when printed
[1] NA
> is.na(mymindate)  # but isn't
[1] FALSE
> dput(mymindate)   # it's actually Inf (the clue was in the warning message to be fair)
structure(Inf, class = "Date")
```

I appreciate that this is probably just how it is and there's no answer except to remember it and not fall into the trap again.

Here's my original problem
I am using ave to find the minimum start date and maximum end date by ID. Some end dates may be missing. I am then using pmin to find the earliest of the end date and two other dates. My problem is in ID3 where the result of the ave(...,max) in 'maxEnd' is NA, then the result of the pmin() in 'Output' is NA.

```
<------------Input Data------------------------><--------Output Data ------------><-Want---->
 ID      DateA      DateB      Start        End   minStart     maxEnd      Output      Want 
  1 2018-01-10       <NA> 2015-05-01 2015-06-28 2015-05-01 2015-08-06  2015-08-06  2015-08-06 
  1 2018-01-10       <NA> 2015-07-06 2015-08-06 2015-05-01 2015-08-06  2015-08-06  2015-08-06 
  1 2018-01-10       <NA> 2015-09-17       <NA> 2015-05-01 2015-08-06  2015-08-06  2015-08-06 
  2       <NA> 2019-12-31 2016-04-20 2016-05-27 2016-04-20 2016-07-16  2016-07-16  2016-07-16 
  2       <NA> 2019-12-31 2016-07-02 2016-07-16 2016-04-20 2016-07-16  2016-07-16  2016-07-16 
  3 2016-02-15       <NA> 2015-07-15       <NA> 2015-07-15       <NA>        <NA>  2016-02-15
```

Here's the code

```
  structure(
    list(
      ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L),
      DateA = structure(c(17541,17541, 17541, NA, NA, 16846), class = "Date"),
      DateB = structure(c(NA,NA, NA, 18261, 18261, NA), class = "Date"),
      Start = structure(c(16556,16622, 16695, 16911, 16984, 16631), class = "Date"),
      End = structure(c(16614,16653, NA, 16948, 16998, NA), class = "Date")
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-6L),
    class = "data.frame"
  )
df$minStart <- with(df, ave(Start,ID,FUN = function(x) min(x , na.rm = T)))
df$maxEnd <- with(df, ave(End,ID,FUN = function(x) max(x , na.rm = T)))
df$Output <- pmin(df$DateA, df$DateB, df$maxEnd, na.rm = T)
```

If I do a similar pmin using the original 'End' column, I get no NA's as expected

```
> pmin(df$DateA, df$DateB, df$End, na.rm = T)
[1] "2015-06-28" "2015-08-06" "2018-01-10" "2016-05-27" "2016-07-16" "2016-02-15"
```

'maxEnd' and 'End' are both dates with NA

```
> df$maxEnd
[1] "2015-08-06" "2015-08-06" "2015-08-06" "2016-07-16" "2016-07-16" NA          
> df$End
[1] "2015-06-28" "2015-08-06" NA           "2016-05-27" "2016-07-16" NA
```

But the NA's in 'maxEnd' appear to be not really NA's

```
> is.na(df$maxEnd)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> is.na(df$End)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

There were warning messages when running the ave() statement (`no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf`). It turns out that the NA's in 'maxEnd' are actually '-Inf'.

```
> dput(df$maxEnd)
structure(c(16653, 16653, 16653, 16998, 16998, -Inf), class = "Date")
> df$maxEnd==-Inf
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> df$maxEnd[df$maxEnd==-Inf]
[1] NA
```

So my sticking plaster fix is to simply replace -Inf with NA with `df$maxEnd[df$maxEnd==-Inf]<-NA` or `df$maxEnd[!is.finite(df$maxEnd)]<-NA`, and I get the output I want

Comment: See also the description `?max`, The minimum and maximum of a numeric empty set are +Inf and -Inf (in this order!) which ensures transitivity, e.g., min(x1, min(x2)) == min(x1, x2). For numeric x max(x) == -Inf and min(x) == +Inf whenever length(x) == 0 (after removing missing values if requested). However, pmax and pmin return NA if all the parallel elements are NA even for na.rm = TRUE.

Comment: I think the answer which I had posted here is relevant to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60632568/date-columns-with-nas-in-r-unexpected-behaviour-with-mutate/ Warning : Read it if you have time and patience :P